Azure Application proxy - Display custom error page instead of default error page
I occasionally get a BadGateway error page when using Azure Application proxy to access an application deployed to an Azure VM (see attached image).  Status code is 502. I want to display my custom error page instead of the default error page. Adding a custom page e.g. 502.html to custom errors section in Web.config doesn't work. How can I get my custom page to display. Thanks.
